# Empty collection bound to LongListSelector cause incorrect view of page

Tags: xaml, data-binding, longlistselector, windows-phone-8

I have Windows Phone 8 page which has a number of controls on it, some of them are LongListSelector controls. If all collections have content everything is displayed correctly.

But if any of the collections bound to the lists are empty all controls below them on the page disappear, i.e. the page looks to be truncated as lots of things are missing.

If I add code to make sure to add at least on item to each collection the page display correctly.

The databinding is done using C#, as shown below.

XAML

```
            <phone:LongListSelector Grid.Row="3" x:Name="PicturesGrid">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Filename}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
```

C#

```
      PicturesGrid.ItemsSource = App.ViewModel.SelectedBird.Pictures;
```

Update: I have noticed that there is a scrollbar present, but however much I scroll I never get down to the bottom.

Comment: Haven't really solved this yet but a workaround is to detect the empty collection and then hide the LongListSelector, now the rest of the page is displayed correctly. But it is a workaround and not a solution... Would not expect the list to go bananas just because the bound Collection is empty.